# How to select random words with unique starting characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a MySQL query to select random words from English dictionary database. However, in my case, the words produced by the query need to be unique in terms of their first two starting characters.

For example, this query does the job of selecting random words, but as you can see, it produces results where the words start with the same characters.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(word) FROM en_english479k WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word)>=12 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

The effect is visible in this screenshot:
[image]

I need to generate words that are completely unique in terms of their starting characters (first two in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I don't generally recommend this approach, but it might be the simplest way to do what you want:

```
select e.word
from (select e.*
      from en_english479k e
      where char_length(word) >= 12 
      order by rand()
     ) e
group by left(word, 2)
order by e.word
limit 10;
```

This uses the MySQL (mis)feature of allowing the `group by` and `select` to not be compatible.  Because you want a *random* word -- and not say the first alphabetically -- I'm more comfortable recommending using this feature in this case.

Comment: Thanks for trying. It sort of works, but unfortunately it generates words that all start with A*... Such as those that start with Aa, Ab, Ac, etc... You see, my original query supported random letters from entire database of words. So I'd have words that start with any alphabet letters.

Comment: @jjj . . . That's just a question of a final `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but I think I just figured it out.

```
SELECT 
word, left(word, 2)
FROM en_english479k 
WHERE word IN 
(
SELECT word FROM en_english479k WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) >= 12 
)
group by left(word, 2)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 50
```